# Could I use ContentDialog in WPF by XAML Islands

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, xaml-islands

In some cases, I want to call the Windows 10 Style Dialog, because it's more beautiful and modern.
But our project is using WPF, we cannot call `ContentDialog` directly.

I'm not sure if XAML Islands can meet my requirement.

I followed the document from MS, add a `WindowsXamlHost` in XAML, and set Title, Content, etc. property in the `ChildChanged` callback, but it throws a exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog.ShowAsync()
   at WpfApp1.MainWindow.WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

XAML

```
<xamlhost:WindowsXamlHost InitialTypeName="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog" ChildChanged="ChildChanged"  />
```

C#

```
        private async void ChildChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowsXamlHost windowsXamlHost = (WindowsXamlHost)sender;

            ContentDialog noWifiDialog = (ContentDialog)windowsXamlHost.Child;

            noWifiDialog.Title = "No wifi connection";
            noWifiDialog.Content = "Check your connection and try again.";
            noWifiDialog.CloseButtonText = "Ok";

            await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

And if I follow the other document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/windowsxamlhost
The same exception shows when I call `ShowAsync()`

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: At least in WinUI3, it should work if you set the `XamlRoot` property: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2504